# How can I change the color of an icon and text at the same time when hovering over with mouse

Tags: html, css, text, hover, icons

I've created 3 icons with text under, you can see the code here http://cssdeck.com/labs/qrpf4z9g

The problem is that if you hover your mouse over an icon, only the icon gets red and the text stays grey, but if you hover over the text first then both icon and text gets red.

my goal is to make the text and the icon red at the same time no matter where you hover first and i can't figure out how.

I'm new to HTML/CSS

Comment: Try using the selector `a:hover span`

Answer (score 3):

Change this:

```
.righticons a span:hover
```

To this:

```
.righticons a:hover span
```

Also, I noticed that upon first hovering each that there is a slight "flash" before showing the red icon. This happens because the icon needs to load its new image - you might consider creating a sprite (at least for each icon) and adjusting only the `background-position` property upon hovering. This will eliminate the flash.

Comment: No problem - note the edit I made as well regarding the flash of the hover images, should help you make things look a little cleaner.

Comment: yes, i was thinking about the flash too, thanks for letting me know, altough i'm not sure how to create a sprite. Would appreciate if you could tell me or i'll have to find it out myself

Comment: Probably too much for me to answer in a comment, but the basic idea is that you are combining your regular and hover images into equally sized blocks in a single image file. Then you use the `background-position` property to define which portion of the image you show. The image changes its position, but doesn't need to load since it was already included in page load with the original image. [This link](http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/basic-link-rollover-as-css-sprite/) should help with setting up your classes, and there are a lot of tutorials available online to check out.

Comment: w3schools also has a decent example here: http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_image_sprites.asp

Comment: Thanks, i figured it out by watching a youtube video :)